# Parallel loop throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel.for

currently I am working on an windows forms application. First I was using a for loop and it was working perfectly good, but the data got bigger and it started to generate the files very slowly. I switched to parallel loop and it throws and exception "Parameter is not valid" on "document.Save(fileName + ".pdf");"

Here is a snippet of my code

```
    private void btnGenerateFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (labelDataSrc.Text == string.Empty || labelTemplateSrcBG.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Template or Data files are not set");
            return;
        }

        ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

        DocumentModel document =  DocumentModel.Load(Globals.pathTemplateSrcBG); ;

        Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
        objExcel.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Globals.pathDataSrc);
        Excel.Worksheet objsheet = objBook.Worksheets["Sheet2"];

        var range = objsheet.UsedRange;
        var rCnt = range.Rows.Count;

        Parallel.For(2, rCnt, i =>
        {
            if (objsheet.Cells.get_Item(i, "D").Value == "BG")
            {
                document = DocumentModel.Load(Globals.pathTemplateSrcBG);
            }
            else if (objsheet.Cells.get_Item(i, "D").Value == "ENG")
            {
                document = DocumentModel.Load(Globals.pathTemplateSrcENG);
            }
            else if (objsheet.Cells.get_Item(i, "D").Value == "RO")
            {
                document = DocumentModel.Load(Globals.pathTemplateSrcRO);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No language of communication on line " + i);
            }

            // Find and replace text.
            document.Content.Replace("*ClnName*", Convert.ToString(objsheet.Cells.get_Item(i, "A").Value) + " " + Convert.ToString(objsheet.Cells.get_Item(i, "B").Value));
            document.Content.Replace("*clnContractNum*", Convert.ToString(objsheet.Cells.get_Item(i, "F").Value));
            document.Content.Replace("*DateSigned*", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));

            string fileName = Convert.ToString(objsheet.Cells.get_Item(i, "F").Value).Replace(@"/", @"-");
            document.Save(fileName + ".pdf");

            labelProgress.Text = i + "/" + rCnt;
            Application.DoEvents();
        });
    }
```

Sorry if my question is stupid, but I was head banging around that and searching for a solution for hours.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of `fileName`?

Comment: I also doubt if you should do COM interop in a multi-threaded environment. Not sure if it breaks. (I guess it will)

Comment: Probably shouldn't use a COM interop in a multi-threaded environment. It gets quickly instable.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: the initialization of `fileName` is immediately prior to the call to `documentSave()`. As for the COM interop question, you are correct to be suspicious, but Excel is STA, and COM will marshal calls back to its owning thread. It obviates any benefit in attempting to use `Parallel` here, but in theory it will be "safe" (that doesn't mean the entire parallelism aspect is bug-free, just that Excel itself won't be the problem).

Comment: I tried switching just for test filename with i and the result is the same.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I can see that, but what is the value at the time it breaks?

Comment: It is a correct value for example "XXX-1-07.12.2010"

Comment: So one thread might be loading a new `document` while another is replacing the content, I dont think that will work..

Comment: Any other ideas how can I speed up the process than?

Comment: You could read the values you need from Excel synchronously and then process the values with a parallel loop.

Comment: Can you give me an example about that.

Comment: You are using multiple shared variables inside `Paralell.for` loop. Try to create this variables inside, one for each thread. First try to move `DocumentModel document =  DocumentModel.Load(Globals.pathTemplateSrcBG);` inside loop and if this don't work try to move `Excel variables` inside loop.